# Conversion Position to float

Tags: ros, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got in a variable Position (which I get from transform.getOrigin) and I want to convert it in a pair of float.
How can I do that?
I'm in Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04 and programming in c++

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189820/conversion-position-to-float/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-12**:
Should we guess which programm language you use? I will never understand why people ask questions with that minimal amount of information.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-12**:
How is this supposed to work? The origin has 3 degrees of freedom and you want to somehow store them in 2 floats?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-12**:
yes this is the case

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-12**:
use typecast float posf = (float) position;

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-12**:
It works, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Solution is  `float posf = (float) position;` given by @bvbdort

---

Originally posted by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) with karma: 133 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-12**:
You could also use the C++ way of casting: `float posf = static_cast<float>(position);`